# Woocomerce round up weight on cart and checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to round up prices on my Woocomerce so when my shipping plugin calculates the costs, it rounds up to 1. Not sure if that makes sense, but let me put an example:

If the total weight of the cart is `6.23 lbs`, I need the cart to show `7 lbs` (lbs = pounds).

I guess I would need to input a function in the `functions.php` file, but not sure where to start, I'm trying to find it myself digging through different online forums, but can not seem to find the slightest clue about it.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but maybe still useful. You can try the [`woocommerce_cart_contents_weight`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_cart_contents_weight/) hook:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_contents_weight', 'round_cart_contents_weight');
function round_cart_contents_weight($weight) {
  return ceil($weight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to round first, then return `$weight`.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_contents_weight', 'round_cart_contents_weight');
function round_cart_contents_weight($weight) {
    $weight = ceil($weight);
    return $weight;
}
```